# How to use visualGroup in contentControl?

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp

Why can't I use `VisualStateGroup` like this?

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup CurrentStateChanged="VisualStateGroup_OnCurrentStateChanged">
        <VisualState x:Name="WideState">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="ControlTemplate" //error here
                        Value="{StaticResource MediafileUnselectedTemplate}" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="ControlTemplate" //error here
                        Value="{StaticResource MediafileUnselectedMobileTemplate}" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

The error is

> TargetPropertyPath“ControlTemplate” Invalid syntax

Comment: You can't change the ControlTemplate.

Comment: What is your `ControlTemplate`. Please always share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue when you seeking debugging help.